# Reasignar categorías con bucle for + if + else

Tags: r, bucle-for, bucles, while, else

Debo hacer un bucle para reasignar los HTD que tengan una n<10 y aquí pongo un ejemplo pequeño del  dataframe con el que estoy trabajando:

```
df1 <- data.frame(HTD= c("49", "50", "51", "52", "53","54","55","56","67","68","69","70","71","72","73","3086","3087","3088","3089","3090","3091","3092"),
                reb = c("3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","6158","6158","6158","6158","6158","6158","6158", ),
              n = c("17","26","29","25","22","6","10","10","10","6","6","6","4","2","3","3","216","1","185","2","209","1","149"),
              año = c("2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2014","2014","2014","2014","2017","2017","2017","2017","2018","2018","2018","2002","2002""2002""2002""2002""2002""2002")
```

Hasta el momento he escrito el siguiente bucle for que hace algunas cosas, pero no todas las que quisiera porque no sé cómo introducir las órdenes:

```
  for (i in 1:(nrow(eje)-1)){
    if((eje[i,3] == eje[i+1,3]      #Debo comprobar que un reb y el siguiente son los mismos. Esto lo hace ok
       & eje[i,5] == eje[i+1,5]     #Debo comprobar que sean del mismo año. Esto ok
       & eje[i,4]<10 & eje[i,4] + eje[i+1,4]>10)){  #cuando n sea menor a 10 y la suma de n más el siguiente sea mayor a 10, entonces
       eje[i,1] = eje[i+1,1]        #Que escriba en i,1 el HTD de i+1,1; es decir el siguiente 
    }else{                          #Si no, (porque a veces sumar i,1 más el siguiente no da 10)
      if(eje[i,4] + eje[i+1,4]<10){ #Que compruebe cuáles son. Esto lo hace ok
         print(paste(eje[i,1]))     #Quisiera decirle que siguiera sumando y acumulando hasta que la suma sea 10, y entonces pusiera el primer HTD de ese subgrupo
       }
    }
  }
```

Usando este código obtengo lo que les muestro abajo con una nueva codificación, aunque hay casos que me siguen quedando sin resolver: por ejemplo:

HTD 68 (antes 67) sigue teniendo n=6. No sé cómo resolverlo
HTD 71 al 73 no sé como programar en el bucle que acumule la suma de ellos hasta que n>=10. Es decir, 2+3+3=8, no cumple. Entonces que lo sume al HTD 70 (que es del mismo reb a pesar de no ser del mismo año pero lo puedo permitir en casos extremos) y compruebe si es >10. En esta caso como la suma ya da 12, que cambie el HTD de 71,72y73 a 70.

Puede que sea necesario hacer más de un bucle para solucionar todas las casuísticas? O usar otras herramientas como repeat o next (no sé cómo se deberían poner)

Gracias!

```
df1 <- data.frame(HTD= c("49", "50", "51", "52", "53","55","55","56","68","69","69","70","71","72","73","3086","3088","3088","3090","3090","3092","3092"),
                reb = c("3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","3005","6158","6158","6158","6158","6158","6158","6158", ),
              n = c("17","26","29","25","22","6","10","10","10","6","6","6","4","2","3","3","216","1","185","2","209","1","149"),
              año = c("2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2014","2014","2014","2014","2017","2017","2017","2017","2018","2018","2018","2002","2002""2002""2002""2002""2002""2002")
```

Comment: No entendí tu anterior pregunta, y me sigue costando entender esta. Por un lado tienes un criterio de asignación del nuevo HTD que parece mirar hacia adelante 67 <- 68, pero por otro lado el ejemplo que das con el HTD=71/72/73, es al revés, asignas un HTD anterior

Comment: Perdón si no me expliqué bien y a lo mejor es más sencillo que todo lo que hice. Lo que quiero del bucle es que, cuando n sea <10, sume ese n del HTD al siguiente hasta que su suma sea >=10, siempre y cuando pertenezcan al mismo reb y al mismo año. Cuando sea >= 10 que pare. En el caso del 71/72/73, su suma da 8, así que podría permitirme asignarlo al HTD anterior o siguiente, siempre que sea del mismo reb a pesar de que no sea el mismo año